# Can't change IIS log field delimter

Tags: asp.net, iis

I would like IIS to write HTTP logs (standard and/or advanced logs) using something other than space as the field delimiter (e.g. pipe, tab, whatever.)

I have tried modifying the delimiter value in the IISAdvancedLogging_schema.xml file located in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\schema:

I've restarted everything, etc. - but no matter what I do, IIS continues to write both standard logs with the space delimiter.

Is there a config elsewhere I am missing?  If the delimiter value cannot be changed, any suggestions about splitting the log fields via space when some of the fields (e.g. user agent) may contain spaces already?

Comment: There is no such configuration and spaces in agent strings are replaced by "+" automatically. Don't post a question without even a reasonable amount of testing, as it won't help you learn things.

Comment: Thanks, Lex.  User agent was a poor example, and you're correct, in the standard logs, the spaces are replaced with +.  In the advanced logs, however, (which I was hoping to use - thus my tweak to the IISAdvancedLogging_schema.xml file) - it maintains spaces and surrounds strings with quotes.  In this case, it would be great if I could change the delimiter and it seems odd the config would exist in the xml file if it had no effect.

Thanks for taking the time to respond in any case.